# How do I pause the app when an alert appears on the screen?

Tags: ios, xcode, uialertview, nstimer

I want to pause the screen when an alert is shown on the screen then undo the pause when the alert is dismissed.  How would I do that?
Here is my view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");
[super viewDidLoad];

[self generate];

[self.answer becomeFirstResponder];

UIAlertView *alert;
{alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
          initWithTitle:@"Welcome to iCanMultiply!" 
          message:@"Tap 'Start' to start the game" 
          delegate: self
          cancelButtonTitle:@"Start" 
          otherButtonTitles: nil];
}

[alert show];
[alert release];

alertTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(showAlert) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)showAlert {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                      initWithTitle:@"Game Over" 
                      message:@"You ran out of time" 
                      delegate:self 
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Try Again" 
                      otherButtonTitles: nil];

[alert show];
[alert release];
}

- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender {
int num = [answer.text intValue];


UIAlertView *alert;
if (num == label.tag)
{
    NSUInteger messageCount = [messagesCorrect count];
    int randomMessageIndex = arc4random() % messageCount;

    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
             initWithTitle:@"Correct!" 
             message:[messagesCorrect objectAtIndex:randomMessageIndex]
             delegate:self 
             cancelButtonTitle:@"Next Question" 
             otherButtonTitles: nil];

    alert.tag = 1;

} else 
{
    NSUInteger messageCount = [messagesIncorrect count];
    int randomMessageIndex = arc4random() % messageCount;

    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
             initWithTitle:@"Wrong!" 
             message:[messagesIncorrect objectAtIndex:randomMessageIndex]
             delegate:self 
             cancelButtonTitle:@"Try Again" 
             otherButtonTitles: nil];
    }

    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (alertView.tag == 1)
    {
        [self generate];

        answer.text = @"";
    }
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    }
```

Please note that my App Delegate is the same as it was when I first started working on the app.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I haven't read your code but in general this is how you pause an NSTimer.

You set up an ivar (in your .h):

```
NSTimer *theTimer;
```

When you want to start it:

```
if (!theTimer) {
    theTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(showAlert) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

When you want to stop it

```
if (theTimer) {
    [theTimer invalidate];
    theTimer = nil;
}
```

Comment: How would I start the timer again after I stop it as the start that you posted only works to start it at the begining

Comment: you do the same thing - you set it to nil when you stop it, and you create again when you want it to start firing